# Writing elements of a frozen set to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, frozenset

I have a frozen set whose elements are like this:

```
{frozenset({'e', 'f'}), frozenset({'a', 'b'}), frozenset({'c', 'd'}),....}
```

I want to write the elements in the frozen set to a pandas dataframe like this:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    c    d
2    e    f
..   ..   ..
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I don't see a reason why someone down voted it. Can that person explain the `why`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your set to a list then create the dataframe.  Let's call your set `dat` in the example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dat), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Yields a separate row in the DataFrame for each set in `dat`.